# Programmatically move files after virus scan

Tags: antivirus

Is it possible to move files programmatically based on virus scan status?

What I want to do is have a set of folders:

Incoming
Scanned
Scanned/Clean
Scanned/Infected
Not Scanned

Files would be dropped into the Incoming folder.  At that point, I would like to kick off the antivirus and scan the files in the Incoming folder.  Once complete, the files would then need to be moved to the appropriate folder, either Clean or Infected.  If, for whatever reason, the file could not be scanned or had trouble scanning, it would be moved to the Not Scanned folder.

I was hoping there would be a way to script this out.  Has anyone ever done anything like this before?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  Anything is possible.  But this is a pretty broad question, you don't specify which AV you're using, or even what environment you're running, so it's unlikely that you're going to get any useful answers.

Comment: At this point...anything.  I don't care about the antivirus and it is a simple Windows environment.  The files are dropped through a POST on to a Windows Server 2003 server.  If I have to download a free antivirus I will.  For the record, the server runs Symantec.

Comment: This is probably better off as a SuperUser question - "which AV will allow me to monitor folder X and move infected files to folder Y"

Comment: Thank you.  I will keep looking for a way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Scan()
{
    string[] uploadPath = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"]);

    foreach(string filePath in uploadPath)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string cleanPath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CleanPath"], fileName);

        try
        {
            Process AV = new Process();

            AV.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            AV.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            AV.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VSApp"];
            AV.StartInfo.Arguments = " -Scan -ScanType 3 -file " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"] + " -DisableRemediation";

            AV.Start();

            string output = AV.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            AV.WaitForExit();

            if (AV.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                File.Move(filePath, cleanPath);
            }

            else if (AV.ExitCode == 2)
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedPath"] + fileName + ".txt"))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("2");
                    tw.Close();
                }

                using (TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedFiles"] + fileName + ".txt"))
                {
                    tw1.WriteLine(AV.StandardOutput);
                    tw1.Close();
                }

                File.Delete(filePath);
            }

            AV.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.ToString().Contains("Could not find file"))
            {
                string failedFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedPath"] + fileName + ".txt";
                string failedFileDesc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedPath"] + fileName + "_ErrorDesc" + ".txt";
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(failedFile))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("2");
                    tw.Close();
                }

                using (TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter(failedFileDesc))
                {
                    tw1.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    tw1.Close();
                }
            }

            else
            {                       
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                if (runCounter == 0)
                {
                    Scan();
                }
                runCounter++;

                string errorFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessErrorPath"] + fileName + ".txt";
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(errorFile))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    tw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created this as a Windows Service.  My OnStart method creates my FileSystemWatcher to watch the Upload Path.  For On Created, I have a method that runs my Scan method and creates my counter and sets it to 0.  My On Error event just logs.  I had an issue where the FileSystemWatcher was trying to open the file before it had been uploaded, hence why I added the sleep.

Finally, I am using Microsoft Forefront's command line scanner.  File path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\mpcmdrun.exe.

Let me know if any questions.

Comment: oh forgot, I log the failed code (2) and the actual failure.  The failure code is used as a flag in SQL.  The actual failure is used by me to figure out what is going on.  In Forefront, 0 is pass, 2 is fail, and I think it is 5 that is unknown.  Unknown happens when the file is opened before it is uploaded or if it is just gone.